# Connecting 2 layer PCB coils together

Tags: pcb, generator, coil

I'd like to make a single phase generator with permanent magnets and coils in order to generate electricity just with my hand.

I already made a disc with 8 holes to put neodymium magnets in it and a support where I will put two layer PCB coils. The coils and the magnets are facing each other and the polarity of adjacent magnets are opposed.

Here is a close up of the coils. They were not designed for this project but I currently only have these.

I'm trying to find a way to connect the coils together and see the voltage generated on an oscilloscope.

I tried with just one coil and I'm seeing an alternating voltage with an amplitude of about 100 mV.

[image]

With two coils in series:

[image]

With 3 coils in series:

[image]

It looks like I need an odd number of coils, but why?

Comment: The last edit deleted images of the coils, could you describe the coils or add the picture back? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage polarity of adjacent coils will be opposite because the polarity of the magnets is as well. If you ignore this, every two coil voltages will sum up to zero. Consider a ferrite plane like wireless chargers have below the coils.

Comment: Alright, so wiring 7 coils would be like having only one coil because there are 3 pairs of adjacent coils whose voltages will sum up to zero, so there is only the voltage of the single coil left.